# How to move data from Coredata to Firestore in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, core-data

I am working on an iOS app in which i have to send data from my coreData to the Firestore. I want to implement following features.

1. Fetching user's data from coreData including each table's attributes and relationships.
2. Sending fetched data to the Firestore.

I am using DFS algorithm to parse the attributes and relationships, creating JSON of each record and then sending it to firestore.

My question is:

is it a right approach or there is a better way ?

Suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service - we are here to assist with existing code you've attempted. The idea is you write some code and when you get stuck, post it and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. Since you are new here, please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, and this is important, Firestore is a NoSQL database which is very different than CoreData datastore, you need to consider what kinds of queries you're going to be running in order to design a workable structure, and then get comfortable writing Firestore code to help you bridge between the two. Experience with NoSQL is vitally important to make it work like you want.